# connect mvc3 application to remote sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

i publish an mvc3 application on a webserver IIS7 and i want to connect my application with a remote SQL server ( different machine)
here is my connection string:

```
connectionstring="server=server;database=db;user Id=user;password=psw;user instance=false" providername="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

i m using entityframework.

i also added the user in the connectionstring to security folder under database in sql management studio with dbo rights.

the problem is i get an error : failed to open a session for the user

SQL exception (0x80131904)

Comment: Can you use Sql Server Management Studio to attempt to connect remotely to the database? Also, are you sure your server name is correct? You can try pinging it from your server to make sure it is reachable by the name you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the user mapping for the login?

You can find the logins under the server folder security -> logins.

Check there is a login mapped to the database user. Select the appropriate login -> properties -> user mapping tab.

The fact that a user exists in a database, does not directly mean that there is a valid login associated with that user. Ensure that a login maps to the database user and that the user has the required database role.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research i just figure out that adding the whole groupe of computers (Domain\Computers) granted me the access to the database. i changed my connectionstring to use `integrated security= sspi`. From the beginning it was a Connection problem.